# Jquery .each function using show() and hide() not working on last checkbox selected

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#comparebut').click(function(){
    var id='';
    $("#recomparebut").show();
    $("#comparebut").hide();
    $('input:checkbox').each(function() {

            id = '';
            id = $(this).val();
            //alert(id);
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {

                //$('#company_' + id).fadeIn(1500,function() {
                    //$('#company_' + id).show();
                //});
            }
            else{
                $('#company_' + id).fadeOut(1500,function() {
                    $('#company_' + id).hide();
                }); 
            }   
     });

  });
});
```

I am trying to hide table rows on a button click event. I am checking the rows based on if a checkbox is selected or not. It works fine but when I have the bottom checkbox selected along with other checkboxes the last table row disappears.

Comment: @dqhendricks - You have high enough privileges to retag. No need to post a comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a closure problem. 
Try :

```
$('#company_' + id).fadeOut(1500,(function(arg) {
    return function() {
        $('#company_' + arg).hide();
    }
})(id));
```

instead of

```
$('#company_' + id).fadeOut(1500,function() {
    $('#company_' + id).hide();
});
```

Explanation about closures : http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Comment: Thanks i will try this as well. but i found a different solution that worked.

Comment: i was able to use the same loop but before my each iteration i called a class.hide on all rows and then showed the rows checked.